# displaying unserialized array data from mysql

Tags: php

i am getting this data from my database and unserlialzing them for my use and want to display the output from these details

```
a:3:{s:8:"firstid";s:9:"photo1977";s:3:"secondid";s:16:"photos/view/1977";s:5:"thirdid";a:1:{i:0;s:40:"uploads/userfiles/201205/09_34_bqqi9.png";}}
```

everything is working as expected except the thirdid . which is giving the output as Array

i am using

```
$firstid = $arr['firstid'];
$secondid = $arr['secondid'];
$thirdid = $arr['thirdid'];
```

to display the output . i am getting the output of firstid & secondid  just fine but thirdid output i am not getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$arr['thirdid]` is an array itself, so `$thirdid` holds an array. Try

```
$thirdid = $arr['thirdid'][0];
```

to get the file path or

```
print_r($arr['thirdid']);
```

to output the array.

**Updated.**

Answer (score 0):

In the serialised data you can see that firstid and secondid are both plain strings, but thirdid is an array, use print_r on it instead of echo to output the data.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 var_dump($thirdid);
```

instand of `echo $thirdid;`